# How to create a automatic process to update record when one field is changed

Tags: mysql, sql-server-2012, etl, informatica

I have been trying to figure this out for some time and needed your help on how to achieve. I have created an ETL process in informatica that takes users from sql server (source db) and adds them in a mysql (target db)
The process involves a number of steps.

Step 1.  - Moves source.dbo.[user] (SQL SERVER) to target.`user`
The user table looks something like this

```
userid   username  profile  disabled
1        A         A         0
2        B         A         0
3        c         B         1
```

This table is upserted when a disabled status is changed and when a new record is added

Step 2 - The new users are then inserted in to target.worker table;
In order to only add users that dont exist in the worker table a left join is used:

```
select wrk.*, usr.* from target.worker 
wrk left join target.user usr on wrk.userid=usr.userid 
where wrk.usrid is null;
```

The worker table looks something like this

```
id   username   userid   disabled
1    A          1        0
2    B          A        0
```

Then after the process runs userid 3 will be added to the worker table

Now here comes the part I cant figure out:
I need to update the users in the worker table when their disabled status changes as well. 
Currently I have mapped the set up to add workers from the user on left join to add only those users that dont exist in the current worker table.
However how can I map it so it updates those records in the worker table when the disabled status changes in the corresponding user table

I hope this makes sense. 
To make it simpler:

When target.[user] is

```
userid   username  profile  disabled
1        A         A         0
2        B         A         0
3        c         B         1
4        D         C         0
```

and target.worker is

```
userid   username  profile  disabled
1        A         A         0
2        B         A         0
3        c         B         0
```

I need a join query with a filter or explanation process so that the worker table both inserts the new record and changes the an existing records disabled status: So it will look like this

```
 userid   username  profile  disabled
    1        A         A         0
    2        B         A         0
    3        c         B         1 <--- Record updated
    4        D         C         0 <-- New record added
```

Comment: So what is the difficulty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a Lookup on target.worker to verify if the record already exist. If it does an NewLookupRow will be 2 (update), use DD_UPDATE in Update Transformation. If it's 1, use DD_INSERT. Use a NewLookupRow != 0 Filter before the Update Trans to skip the rows you already have in target.

Comment: Thank you, I couldnt quite figure out how to use lookup tool in informatica cloud. But instead I created another filter on the joined table for the update records

Comment: oh - you did not indicate it was about the Informatica Cloud. Joiner is the way to go as well.